# Android Studio Network Connection media Player

Tags: android, mp3

So for my android project I have to establish a network connection to a website that can play Mp3 music. I was just wondering if that was at all possible. for an Operating System project?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible. but there is a catch. either you have to build a server side streaming capabilities or you have to make the mp3s downloadable. so the app can temporary download the mp3 and play it. there are few other methods also. but it is very possible.